# Trying to make a user stats command in discord.py 1.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
#Returns User stats for the server
@client.command()
async def user(ctx, member:discord.User=None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.message.author
        pronoun = "Your"
    else:
        pronoun = "Their"
    name = f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}"
    status = member.Status
    joined = member.joined_at
    role = member.top_role
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{pronoun} name is {name}, {pronoun} status is {status}, They joined at {joined}, {pronoun} rank is {role}")
```

Im trying to make a user stats command, it originally worked as an event on message but i want to make it a command so you can see another user's stats but i keep getting member object has no attribute status error in terminal, what am i doing wrong in this code?

Comment: [`Member.status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.status) has a lowercase `s`.

Comment: I tried that and it still says member object has no attribute status, what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `member` object is actually of type `User` because you are using the `User` converter. Use the `Member` converter instead.

Comment: that was the issue, Thanks a lot!